# Access mysql without password, running as OS root

Tags: mysql, debian

Is there a way for user root to access `mysql`, with privileges, without knowing the password?

I am a more used, without being an expert, to PostgreSql, and I know that with the default Debian install of the latter I can just type:

```
# su - postgres
$ psql
```

I have root access to the server I am working on, but the administrator has not created a MySQL account for me, and is not reachable.

Considering that I could very well just tamper with MySQL files, I suppose there must be a way for me to log in, but I haven't found it yet.

There is a mysql user, but it seems like it doesn't work as with the postgres user:

```
# su - mysql
# whoami
root
# mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Comment: Not that I know of.  That doesn't feel very secure, does it?  Did you mean "tamper"?

Comment: @duffymo Thanks for the spelling correction. I don't feel that giving access to the database to someone that anyway has access to the database files is insecure, though As I said, I'm really no expert. I suppose it wouldn't work that way with PostgreSql if there was a concern?

Comment: I don't think any database ought to grant access if you don't have credentials.  All the ones I know of work that way.  Your feelings aren't shared by database vendors.  Best solution is to talk to the admin and sort it out properly.  If it were me, I would not be giving you root access.  I'd restrict you to your database and nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been pointed out that this is not a good practice, but I have found a way.

`mysqld` has a command-line switch named [`--init-file`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_init-file) which refers to a file containing SQL commands that are executed when the server starts.

So I was able to create a user for myself with those commands:

```
# echo CREATE USER 'scozy'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '****'; > /root/init.sql
# /etc/init.d/mysql stop
# mysqld --init-file=/root/init.sql
# /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```